# Paging in Microsoft Graph ASP.NET Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api

I am using the ASP.NET MVC Framework for Microsoft Graph to query for information about employees. The results that I am querying for are being sent one page at a time, and I was wondering if it is possible to receive the results all at once rather than page by page? I looked through all of the files that are included in the ASP.NET MVC Framework on Visual Studio and couldn't find anything that controls the rate that results are sent. If this is how Microsoft Graph is set up by default, is it possible to override?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked [Use query parameters to customize responses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters)?

You can control how many records are returned in your request using the **$top** operator documented in the link above but that is limited to the maximum Graph API will give you. When you have a huge list of users and really need all of them at once, you can paginate and accumulate on your app.

Here is a way to paginate through users using .net

```
var users = new List<User>();
var usersPage = await graphServiceClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();
users.AddRange(usersPage.CurrentPage);
while (usersPage.NextPageRequest != null)
{
   usersPage = await usersPage.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
   users.AddRange(usersPage.CurrentPage);
}
```